# Validar método destroy laravel que no se pueda borrar registro relacionados con otra tabla

Tags: php, laravel

tengo una tabla llamada articulo, la misma esta relacionada con la tabla ventas como hago para validar un mensaje de error en mi metodo destroy para cuando un usuario intente eliminar un producto que tiene  ventas?

```
  public function destroy($id)
  {
      $art=Art::findOrFail($id);
      $art->delete();
   
    return Redirect::to('movimientos/art');
   }
```

yo quiero poner un mensaje que diga: que si "tiene movimientos asociados no se pueda eliminar", ya que si no se puede borrar sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Modelo Articulo

```
 public function ventas()
  {
      return $this ->hasMany(Ventas::class,'id','id');
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

validalo en el catch. asi lo hago yo:

```
public function delete()
{
    try 
    {
        SeccionesMenu::destroy($this->modelId);
        $this->modalConfirmDeleteVisible = false;
        $this->resetPage();
    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) 
    {
        if($e->getCode()=="23000")
            $this->addError('error', 'Hay menus relacionados a esta sección, Favor de borrarlos primero');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, por favor añade más información técnica de tu respuesta de forma en que se entienda bien qué hace tu código.